# Accessing DB2 Database in ACE 11 ESQL using ODBC

Tags: db2, odbc, ibm-integration-bus

I need to access DB2 database in ESQL, App Connect Enterprise v11. 
I have a DB2 installed in my lap, and data can be queried.
I add a ODBC data-source in windows and the test connection succeeds. 
In the ace console I set the ODBC resource as

`mqsisetdbparms ACENODE2 -n odbc::books -u db2root -p nable@123`

where `ACENODE2` is my Integration Node and books is my database. Only 
confusion I have is should I give the schema or database name in the compute node data-source  tab
which I tried both and failed.

My ESQL code is

`SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.books[] = SELECT P.BOOK_ID, P.TITLE, P.TOTAL_PAGES, P.ISBN FROM Database.books.books AS P;`

where books database has a books table. Warning that I'm getting is

`Unresolvable database table reference "Database.books.books".`

With the warning, I deployed the project, (which is a simple REST API fetching data from a database)
The below error I got as response. here getAllBooks is my message flow. Any guidance is very much appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1>
    <p>
        BIP2230E: Error detected whilst processing a message in node 'gen.TestBase.getAllBooks
        (Implementation).Compute'. <br>
BIP2348E: Error detected while attempting to obtain a connection to data source 'db2root' of type 'ODBC' using userid ''.
        <br>
BIP2393E: Database error: ODBC return code '-1' from data source 'DB2ROOT' using ODBC driver manager 'odbc32.dll'.
        <br>
BIP2322E: Database error: SQL State 'IM002'; Native Error Code '0'; Error Text '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified'.
</p>
        <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried ...`SELECT ... FROM Books` or `...SELECT ... FROM your-schema.Books` ?  In the database, check the exact case of the tablename (in `syscat.tables`) and only if it has mixed case letters then you need to double-quote its name in the query. You can also see the schema-name in the `syscat.tables` entry for table books, and you can reference that schema in your query. Db2 table names can have 1 or 2 parts usually (schema.table or just table) and three part names are only valid in specific situations.  Create the DSN with correct 32-bit or 64-bit odbcad32 to match your app bitness.

Comment: @apologies for the late reply one by one I checked the points you mentioned and nothing seems to be out of order. SELECT * FROM books; returned data, I'm using the correct same case in the compute node, the installation is 64 bit and I have verified.

Comment: Which version of ACE are you using (which fix pack level)? If it is not the latest, then I would recommend updating and retrying. Also, you should run the mqsicvp utility as recommended in the documentation.